# Intercept method invocation

Tags: c#, aop, postsharp

I'm trying out my hands with PostSharp and have a concrete problem I'd like to start out with.

I'd like to like to decorate foo

```
public class Baz<T> {

   [MyAspect]
   T foo

   public void myBar<T>(T self) {
   //...
   }
}
```

and then given the code

```
foo.myBar();
```

I'd like for PostSharper (or similar) to rewrite (at build time) the method invocation into

```
myBar(foo);
```

However I can find an aspect to decorate a method with an intercept all calls to that method but not an aspect I can decorate a field (or property) with and then intercept method invocations on said field

**EDIT** I'm not locked on decorating the field. Decorating the class would suffice if I can get a hold of the internal of the class as an abstract syntax tree of some sort

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking for. Are you basically asking for an extension method, but only for a specific field?

Comment: @svick yeah that's pretty close of the goal 'I'm trying to achieve. The scoping rules and overload resolution rules would be slightly different

Comment: Please try to describe your problem. For me this looks like you are trying to get an assumed solution to work.

Comment: Why would you want this?  Why not just put `myBar(foo);` in place of `foo` and be done with it?  Or have `myBar(foo)` call the other method?  Why does this need to be done using interception?

Comment: @Amy why use an instance method in the first place then. After all they are all translated to simple function calls where the instance variable as the first parameter :) The answer to both is that sometimes syntax matters. For more information see how role methods are implemented in Marinv (fulloo.info) or how they are implemented in the DCI gem Maroon

Comment: @PVitt my actual problem is rewritting foo.myBar() to mybar(foo). As svick pointed out it's much like extension methods. So presume a pre c# 3.0 world and my question was "How can I create extension methods using postsharp" (The accessability of the method and the overload resolution differes from extension methods but that has nothing to do with the rewrite but all to do with why I can't just use extension methods)

Comment: @RuneFS Beg your pardon. but I still don't got the problem. Trying to use extension methods still seems to be a solution. What problem do you want to solve using extension methods?

Comment: @PVitt the problem I have is simply `rewrite foo.myBar() to myBar(foo)` that's the _actual_ problem.

Comment: @RuneFS So the problem is the look of your code?

Comment: @PVitt no the problem is to write a program that can walk through my code an as part of the build rewrite the code, just as the C# compilers does for iterator blocks, async statements, extensionmethods, LINQ and a few others. This particular feature I need is not part of the C# compiler rewrite which is why I need to create it with e.g postsharp or from scratch with Roslyn

Comment: @RuneFS Sorry, but that again seems like the solution. WHY do you need a program to parse your code?

Comment: @PVitt Because that's what I do. I write compilers and other parser based tools